# Understanding the Optimization Process of next/image in Next.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, next-images

I'm currently working with Next.js and the next/image component for image rendering. I've been using it to optimize image loading in my application, but I'm curious about the technical details of how it works under the hood. Specifically, I'd like to know if it makes any API calls during the optimization process.

Here's what I understand so far:

- next/image provides features like lazy loading, responsive images, and format selection to optimize image loading.
- It generates multiple versions of images in different sizes and formats during the build process.
- It selects the most suitable image format based on browser support.
- It supports lazy loading by default, and you can specify responsive image dimensions.

However, I couldn't find information on whether next/image makes any API calls during this optimization process. My goal is to gain a deeper understanding of its internal workings. Any insights or resources on this topic would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are you talking about scenario where you've imported a file in the code and pass it to `Image` or scenario where you have image to the url and do `<Image src={url} />`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you have code like this:

```
<Image width={180} height={37} src="/test.jpg" />
```

When the component is rendered, default loader will change the src url to `/_next/image?url=/test.jpg&w=384&q=75` which in turn contains all the parameters needed for optimization, like quality and width. On the server side NextJS will then optimize and crop/resize the image using [sharp](https://www.npmjs.com/package/sharp). These optimized images are then cached so that subsequent requests to the same image don't require optimizing it again. If you're hosting on Vercel, it would use Vercel's own image optimization service.

Note that it's also possible to make [custom loader](https://nextjs.org/docs/pages/building-your-application/optimizing/images#loaders) for image optimization. This will allow you to use any image optimization service you want. Custom loaders are implemented by simply giving the image component a function which takes src, width, quality and returns the url where to load the optimized image. Typically you put the quality and width as url params just like the default loader does.

```
const imageLoader = ({ src, width, quality }) => {
  return `https://example.com/${src}?w=${width}&q=${quality || 75}`
}
```

Comment: Does the optimization process happen in both production and development or only production?

Comment: Both, added it to the answer.

Comment: @FINDarkside I appreciate the explanation of how Next.js and the next/image component work internally.

I'm now curious about the image optimization service provided by Vercel. If I host my Next.js application on Vercel, does it automatically utilize this image optimization service for the images generated by the next/image component?

I ask because I'm planning to launch a web app with a substantial number of images, possibly in the thousands. Understanding whether Vercel's image optimization service is being used will help me calculate potential costs and optimize my budget accordingly

Comment: Yes, if you host on Vercel their pricing will apply. https://vercel.com/docs/image-optimization/limits-and-pricing#pricing